# Trouble with figure output in matlab

Tags: matlab

I try to get the figure from the large data file (about 400 Mb) using Matlab 2010b on Windows 7 x64 ultimate.
Here my code

```
function psi12
OP = load ('20_01_w=0-021_OP_Ksi1.txt'); 
z=OP;
tt=length(z);
x=linspace(0,20,41);
t=linspace(0,0.01*tt,tt);
contourf(x,t,z)
xlabel('x','Fontsize',24)
ylabel('t','Fontsize',24)
title(['V = 0.1, \omega = 0.021'],'Fontsize',20)
```

But after the launch this code first I obtain figure with white background. And only after very long waiting (about 3-4 hours) I have desired contour plot. But further editing of the figure is practically impossible, because very long response for any commands in figure menu is observed.
It's interesting that for another even larger data files (about 900 Mb or 1 Gb) I get contour plot significantly faster (within 10-15 minutes) and I can edit this figure without any problems with response from figure menu.

Do you know any solution of this problem?

Comment: Downsample `z`? so if it's 2D then `Zds = z(1:nx:end, 1:ny:end)` and make `nx` and `ny` suitable values so that they reduce the size of the image without excluding vital information.

Comment: after loading can you do a `whos OP`?

Comment: another idea - the performance of contour quite likely depends on how many contour lines you have . So it could be that by bad luck you get way too much (think noisy data with a contour around every other pixel). Maybe you can set the levels to a more reasonable value - or somehow remove some noise.

Comment: Sorry for the long response. It works, a lot thanks to Dan, bdecaf and markotka.

Answer (score 1):

Beside what Dan suggested, another thing you should do is to load the data directly into z:

```
z = load ('20_01_w=0-021_OP_Ksi1.txt');
```